# ActionScript beginner, understanding for-each

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Why this:

```
    for each (var dieListener:Object in dieListeners)
    {
        var f:Function = (dieListener as Function);
        f();
    }
```

..doesn't work, if this:

```
    for (var i:int=0; i<dieListeners.length; i++)
    {
        var f:Function = (dieListeners.getItemAt(i) as Function);
        f();
    }
```

..works!?

(the first one simply doesn't enter the for loop, but the second do!)

Comment: Did you know you're missing the 'each' keyword? It should be something like 'for each (params) {}'

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway added, still the same behaviour..

Comment: What kind of object is diesListeners ?

Comment: @David ArrayList, but what's the difference if the second code works?

Comment: Just wanted to be sure the type was supported by for each

Comment: What happens if you do this : for each(var f in dieListeners) { trace( ObjectUtil.toString(f)) } ? Do you see anything in the console ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ArrayList doesn't support for each. Try to use an ArrayCollection instead.

Comment: Correct. The compiler should say something meaningful in cases like this.. Thanks!